# Enable GZip compression on serving files

Tags: php, apache, gzip

Hiii,
I want to compress output [excluding image only] using GZIP in PHP, how to do so for each type of files [PHP, CSS, JS, HTML] ?
I know the code to work with PHP file only.

Comment: You can't use PHP to compress data that is isn't being processed by PHP. Get your webserver to do it directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use mod_deflate module of Apache 
more info

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Answer (score 1):

Place this line in your page before any headers or other output.

`ob_start("ob_gzhandler");`

And for other files you can serve them through php, this could be used if you have mod-rewrite, but no mod-deflate or mod-gzip

Comment: but if i've lots of files then in that case this looks like impossible to do !